# Как сменить классификацию с img на video в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть скрипт, который переключает изображения при клике на них. Мне нужно чтобы этот скрипт делал тоже самое, но с видео-файлами формата mp4. Но с одним важным условием! Следующее видео не должно переключаться, пока не закончилось предыдущее.

Надеюсь на Вашу помощь! Заранее спасибо!

```
<script>
var i = 0;
var imgs = new Array('001A.jpg', '002A.jpg', '003A.jpg');

function imgsrc() {
  var image = document.getElementById("image");
  image.src = imgs[i = ++i % 3];
  console.log(image.src);
}
</script>

<img id="image" src="001A.jpg" onClick="imgsrc();">
```

Comment: непонятно, ты хочешь автоматическое переключение или по клику?

Comment: У [video->HTMLMediaElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement) есть различные свойства и события.
Например `duration` и `currentTime`. Первое что можно попробовать повешать событие конца `ended`, и только после него активировать переход по клику.
Но не факт что оно верно отработает, надо пробовать различные комбинации, а это долго и муторно :(

Comment: @Grundy По клику. Я нажимаю на первое видео, оно запускается, доходит до конца и останавливается, я по нему кликаю и запускается следующее и тд.

Comment: а если ты кликнешь пока видео играет?

Comment: @Grundy Клик во время воспроизведения видео не должен учитываться